# Sitecore won't publish element, even though the unpublishing date hasn't been reached

Tags: publishing

We have recently made some changes to a newer version of one of our elements in Sitecore. Upon revisiting the element, we get the error message: "if you publish now, the item will not be visible on the web site as the unpublishing date has been reached".

However, we have specified no dates for the beginning or end of publishing. How is this error happening and how can we mitigate it?

Comment: Did you check the publishing viewer to get an indication? And are you sure there is nothing set - the Publishing section is empty?

Comment: @max do you have anything set  at all for unpublish date?

Answer (score 1):

I've got a few articles for you to align on the publishing functionality:

1. [How does the publishing work (in technical terms)](https://github.com/mitikov/KeepSitecoreSimple/wiki/How-does-publishing-work)
2. [Typical reasons why smth is not published](https://github.com/mitikov/KeepSitecoreSimple/wiki/How-to-figure-out-why-new-content-is-not-showing-up#bonus---typical-reasons)

From the message, it sounds like one of the items may have old/obsolete `publishable to` date left in the self-or-parent hierarchy.

I'd recommend inspecting selecting `Standard fields` , `Publishable` tab to find the culprit.